# How to navigate from the root dir, especially one or more levels up/out

Tags: view, root, sapui5

I am further exploring OpenUI5/SAPUI5 library for displaying data into it. This time, I try to load a XML view, but the file is not found. This is not a very big issue, but it is frustrating, as it only works if I put the view file into a specific folder. I searched and found a bunch of tutorials which give help on how to organize your project. I followed the described steps, but it's not working.

**What I am trying to achieve:** Put the view files in a folder of my preference.

**The problem:** The library can't find those views.

**What I've done so far:**

1. I have an MVC project (C# + html).
2. In my view (lets call it ViewName.cshtml) I have the following:

   ```
   <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
       src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/OpenUI5/sap-ui-core.js")'
       data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
       data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table'
       data-sap-ui-compatversion='edge'
       data-sap-ui-preload='async'
       data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
           "sap.views": "./"
       }'>
   </script>

   //...

   @* Trying to load the xml view *@
   <script>
       sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
           new sap.ui.xmlview({
               viewName: "sap.views.A1"
           }).placeAt("testView");
       });
   </script>
   ```

I have a folder Views, which holds the folder OpenUI5, which holds two things - ViewName.cshtml and a folder named 'view'. Into that folder 'view', I have A1.view.xml, which is as simple as:

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Text text="Hello!" />
</mvc:View>
```

In the docs, they say, that

```
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sap.views": "./"
    }'
```

replaces sap.views in the viewName property of the params object, given to new sap.ui.xmlview() with what you define in place of './' If you write './', then you mean "the root directory".

Here comes the main issue and misunderstanding. Everywhere in those tutorials and documentation, they say, that the root dir is the one, which holds your html page index.html. So, I suppose, that in my case, the root dir should be the folder OpenUI5, which holds ViewName.cshtml. I tried renaming it to index.cshtml, which had no effect at all.

What I have found out is that the root dir is actually the dir where sap-ui-core.js is located. I tested and came to this conclusion by removing data-sap-ui-resourceroots='' from the script tag, which initializes the library and naming my view just A1:

```
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
    new sap.ui.xmlview({
        viewName: "A1"
    }).placeAt("testView");
});
```

Now, if A1.view.xml is in the folder, where sap-ui-core.js is, then it is found and rendered.

I tried to put A1.view.xml into the subfolder 'sap' of the folder where sap-ui-core.js is located and render it like this:

```
    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.ui.xmlview({
            viewName: "sap.A1"
        }).placeAt("testView");
    });
```

Once again, it's working.

**My question: how to go up a level?** Say in Views, I add a folder as a sibling to the folder OpenUI5(which holds ViewName.cshtml) and it is called OpenUI5XmlViews, where I put A1.view.xml.

sap-ui-core.js is located in Scripts/OpenUI5/, and the folder Scripts is a sibling of the folder Views. Having all this in mind, for it to work, I expect to be able to do something like this:

```
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
    src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/OpenUI5/sap-ui-core.js")'
    data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
    data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table'
    data-sap-ui-compatversion='edge'
    data-sap-ui-preload='async'
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sap.xmlviews": "../../../Views/OpenUI5XmlViews"
    }'>
</script>

    sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.ui.xmlview({
            viewName: "sap.xmlviews.A1"
        }).placeAt("testView");
    });
```

I think this should produce the path /Views/OpenUI5XmlViews/A1.view.xml, but it does not. Please, help me how to achieve it? Thank you.

**edit:** Here is what I get in the browser console as an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: resource sap/views/A1.view.xml could not be loaded from ../../../Views/OpenUI5XmlViews/A1.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Reason: Not Found
```

Does not work like this as well:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: resource sap/views/A1.view.xml could not be loaded from ./././Views/OpenUI5XmlViews/A1.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Reason: Not Found
```

Comment: the reference path is not relative to sap-ui-core.js but to your html file.

Comment: @Ash - OK, but I have written in the question: "I tested and came to this conclusion by removing data-sap-ui-resourceroots='' from the script tag, which initializes the library and naming my view just A1.
Now, if A1.view.xml is in the folder, where sap-ui-core.js is, then it is found and rendered." In 1 word - if A1.view.xml is together with sap-ui-core.js, then it is working. I don't want to argue, I just did quite a few tests and this was one of them and I am sharing with you what I have observed. The html file is in a place separated from the sap-ui-core.js

Comment: instead set the resources to the folder views, try to set the resources name of index folder and call the view using the name space with the folders, like sap as namespace and call the view as sap.folder1.folder2.A1

Comment: @Guto - OK, doing it the way you suggest, it "proves to be alive". Error: resource sap/views/A1.view.xml could not be loaded from /Views/OpenUI5XmlViews/A1.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Now, it has started to look in the right directory using data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "sap.views": "/Views/OpenUI5XmlViews" }'. Now the problem is - why the view is missing as it actually is there?

Comment: change you index.html to load the view sap.Views.OpenUI5XmlViews.A1

Comment: OK, now it is clear to me, that ./ is not working. It does not get transformed to the actual relative path (/sap/ui/... or sth like this) and the error in browser console says: ...could not be loaded from ./A1.view.xml

Comment: @Guto, thank you for your continuous help :)! However, if I try the way you suggest like this: new sap.ui.xmlview({
                viewName: "sap.Views.OpenUI5XmlViews.A1"
            }).placeAt("testView"); it says ...could no be loaded from /Scripts/OpenUI5/sap/Views/OpenUI5XmlViews/A1.view.xml To me, this means, that it wants the dir of the views to be a child (direct or not) of the dir where sap-ui-core.js is. In my case, this "root" dir is /Scripts/OpenUI5. I tried  this with and without setting data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "sap.views": "./" }'

Comment: No, the root is your index.html folder, look my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a ressource root:

```
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sap.xmlviews": "../../../Views/OpenUI5XmlViews"
 }'>
```

So you define a kind of namspace "sap.xmlviews" which points to folder path relative to your index.html file. That has nothing to do with your sap-ui-core.js framewrok path.

So if you try a view A.view.xml from your defined ressourceroot you have to write ist like sap.xmlviews.A . Look at this example: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/1409791afe4747319a3b23a1e2fc7064.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, but for me it's not working. "Error: resource sap/views/A1.view.xml could not be loaded from ./view/A1.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors." It displays this error no matter if I have a folder view with the view A.view.xml inside and that folder is placed in the dir, where the index page is or in the dir where sap-ui-core.js is. My resource root: data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"sap.views": "./view"}'.

Comment: It only works if I don't define a resource root but call it like this: new sap.ui.xmlview({viewName: "view.A1"}). This way, it searches in /Scripts/OpenUI5(here sap-ui-core.js is located)/view/A1.view.xml and finds it. If I call it like new sap.ui.xmlview({viewName: "A1"}), then the error says, that the framework expects the view to be in /Scripts/OpenUI5/A1.view.xml. For me, defining a resource root is not working at all or am I doing something wrong? Somehow it finds the views, but I always have to put them in a child dir of sap-ui-core.js.

Answer (score 0):

Alright,

I don't know what are you doing but a good pratice is create you directory tree using mvc pattern:

```
webapp 
+model
+view
++A1.view.xml
+controller
++A1.controller.js
+index.html
```

And set your name space for the root folder:

```
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
    src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/OpenUI5/sap-ui-core.js")'
    data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
    data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table'
    data-sap-ui-compatversion='edge'
    data-sap-ui-preload='async'
    data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
        "sap.myapp": "./"
    }'>
</script>
```

so youi can call your view in index.html:

```
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.ui.xmlview({
            viewName: "sap.myapp.view.A1"
        }).placeAt("testView");
    });
```

Comment: OK, let me show important parts of my dir structure: Myproj.MVC +Scripts ++OpenUI5 +++view ++++A1.view.xml +++sap ++++A1.view.xml +++main.js +++sap-ui-core.js +Views ++OpenUI5 +++Contragents.cshtml (this is actually the index page) +++OpenUI5XmlViews ++++A1.view.xml +Contragents ++ContragentsController.cs

Comment: So far, I managed to show the view in only two ways: new sap.ui.xmlview({
            viewName: "sap.A1" // the one in folder Scripts/OpenUI5/sap
        }).placeAt("testView"); or new sap.ui.xmlview({
            viewName: "view.A1" // and the one in folder Scripts/OpenUI5/view
        }).placeAt("testView"); no matter if I define a resource-root or not.

Comment: sorry but it is a mess, if you set "./" as root and let say that the nampespace is sap. you could call the vuew by sap.OpenUI5XmlViews.A1. But I think you could organize your project separating your files.Maybe you could create a folder call client where you put the files that will be loaded in client side like openui5 files and cs files sou you set the root namespace as ./client/ and call in the cshtml namespace.view.A1